# Apache .htaccess mod_rewrite multiple RewriteRules

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have migrated my site to a wordpress site and set up the permalinks to be the post name. I need to add a rewriteRule to take anything from a cgi directory and just send them to the home page Ive tried:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
RewriteRule ^cgi(.*)$ http://example.com
```

Removing the [L] from the wordpress rule and adding the last line but it still doesnt work. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: to be more clear it re routs if I type example.com/cgi but not if I type example.com/cgi/dynamic.uri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep `L` flag as before and your `cgi` rule should be placed below `RewriteBase` line:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^cgi(.*)$ / [L,NC,R]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```